# pip install from a gitosis

Tags: git, ssh, pip, gitosis

I have working gitosis repo. If I do

```
git clone git@server:repo.git
```

it clones the repo correctly. However, it does not work if I do:

```
git clone ssh://git@server:repo.git

Cloning into repo...
ssh: connect to host  port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The problem is that when I use `pip` I I do:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@server:repo.git
```

and of course yields:

```
Cloning into repo...
ssh: connect to host  port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If I want to do:

```
pip install git+git@server:repo.git
```

I get

```
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'git+git@server:repo.git', 'at', '+git@server:repo.git')
```

Is there a way to have pip or gitosis configured so I can make it work?

Thanks,

(please avoid 'use gitolite', I would if I could)

Answer (score 8):

I would rather use the [ssh uri syntax](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04#section-3.3) (rather than the SCP syntax)

```
git clone git+ssh://git@server/repo.git
```

Comment: To anyone looking at this and thinking, "That IS what I did!", notice that after `server` there is a `/` rather than a `:`. This is what I needed to change from my usual syntax in order to get pip to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To install, you should only have to run:

```
pip install git+git://host/path_to_repo/repo.git
```

So for your example:

```
pip install git+git://server/path_to_repo/repo.git
```

Comment: I cannot do it like this. I need to access via ssh.

Comment: Sorry, just re-read your original post. I actually think it might be a firewall issue, as git uses different ports to ssh. What happens if you do a ssh -T to your server, are you able to connect?