# Why doesn't my SSH key work for connecting to github?

Tags: ssh, github, ssh-keys

Note: I'm not a newb, and I've done this a gazillion times, but for some reason today it decided not to work.

I keep getting the `Permission denied (publickey).` error message when trying to connect to github via SSH or when trying to clone a repo, even after remaking the ssh key and adding it to "SSH Keys" in my account.

This is what I tried to do *ten times* today without success:

1. make a key with ssh-keygen.
2. open ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub with Gedit or Notepad++ and copy the contents.
3. Go to account settings on github.com
4. Go to SSH Keys
5. Click on the Add Key button.
6. give the key a title
7. paste the key into the key box.
8. Save the key (enter my github password to verify).

And now, when I try doing `ssh github.com` it just won't work.... What in the world? Am I just too tired right now or am I missing something?

Here's the output from `ssh -vvv github.com`

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0f 4 Jan 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/trusktr/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "github.com" from file "/home/trusktr/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/trusktr/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 122/256
debug2: bits set: 510/1024
d    ebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "github.com" from file "/home/trusktr/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/trusktr/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "207.97.227.239" from file "/home/trusktr/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/trusktr/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/trusktr/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug2: bits set: 497/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_rsa (0x14cce60)
debug2: key: trusktr@rocketship (0x14ce2b0)
debug2: key: /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: trusktr@rocketship
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/trusktr/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: If you scroll down that directions page, it tells you to use `ssh-add` to add the key.  Did you do that?

Comment: are you trying to ssh into github, or push/pull to a repo with ssh authentication?

Comment: If you are on Windows, did you defined `%HOME%`? And anyway, an `ssh -vvv github.com` would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018551/heroku-push-master-ssh-problem/6018945#6018945 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461

Comment: On the "review your public ssh keys" side, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766682/how-can-i-review-my-ssh-key-for-github/9766805#9766805

Comment: @AdamMihalcin Yeah, I tried that but no difference.

Comment: @YenTheFirst Yes I am, which I've done many times before without a problem.

Comment: @VonC I posted the output from `ssh -vvv github.com` above. Also, my fingerprint from `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` matches with the one listed in SSH Keys on github.com.... After adding the config file as suggested in your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461 it worked! I never needed this before though. Why do I need it now?

Comment: @AdamMihalcin - you nailed it. thx.
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGcpVQlhbuI

Answer (score 162, accepted):

The [GitHub ssh setup](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/) mentions testing your GitHub connection with:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
```

That follow the [ssh uri syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817976/pip-install-from-a-gitosis/9835653#9835653) (also illustrated in "[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835653/6309)").

But you did:

```
ssh github.com
```

(without any user). In that case, ssh reverts to the [SCP syntax](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php), which relies on a `~/.ssh/config` file, with a section "`github.com`", to list:

- the user
- the hostname
- (and optionally the public key location, but by default it will try `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`)

To change it to a regular SSH URL, don't edit directly your .git/config file, as shown below.
Use the [command `git remote set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emset-urlem):

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

---

As noted by [STEEL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/942317/steel) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960897/why-doesnt-my-ssh-key-work-for-connecting-to-github/9963769#comment136488846_9963769), should your private SSH key have a passphrase, you can [add it to the `ssh-agent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22272892/6309) with:

- on Mac: `ssh-add -K` or [(2023) `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28040650/6309)
- on Linux/Windows: [`ssh-add`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43165419/6309)

Comment: I think you meant git@guthub.com:port/repo.git. You already supplied the username before the @ sign, and especially for those hitting their own git servers that may use a custom port number for SSH (for example, Atlassian's BitBucket does this) after the colon is typically where the port number would go. Or am I missing something in your syntax?

Comment: @SeligkeitIstInGott using the port in the remote means using an URI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) instead of the SCP syntax (which predates the OpenSSH URI -- https://www.ssh.com/ssh/#history-of-the-ssh-protocol): `ssh://git@github.com:port/repo.git`. If you don't use `ssh://` scheme, then it is an SCP syntax, in which the port is specified separately.

Comment: I was having an issue where I could "connect" to my github account in sourcetree, but if I tried to clone a repository it would ask for a password and not accept anything. After running ssh -T git@github.com then I was immediately able to clone a repo from Github successfully in SourceTree. My bet is that Atlassian (sourcetree) doesn't want to make it easy to connect to Github since they want you to use Bitbucket. Oh well, it works now!

Comment: additionally you can save the key `ssh-add -K` permanently

Comment: @STEEL Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Note: [`-K` is now obsolete for macOS versions Monterey (12.0) and more recent versions](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-ssh-add-illegal-option----apple-use-keychain).

Answer (score 123):

I had a similar problem, github did not use my SSH key. I always had to enter my username and password.

I've been looking at .git/config, under [remote "origin"] there was:

```
    url = http://github.com/path/to/repository
```

or

```
    url = https://github.com/path/to/repository
```

I changed the line into

```
    url = ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repository
```

and then it worked.

Comment: Good catch.  The git way of doing this without editing the config file would be the following: 1. `git remote`, which will list all your remote repositories. In my case it was `origin`  2. `git remote remove <remote name that you found>`  3. `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repository-name.git`

Comment: In addition to @nomad's suggestions, you'll also need to use `--set-upstream origin master` the next time you push (or perhaps before that)

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10

Comment: This worked for me but broke another feature I created. I created git-open command to open the repo URL in one's browser, and to get the URL it it reads from the remote origin. I'm still fairly new to all this, but is there a way I can have the best of both worlds?

Comment: Thank you! I was looking everywhere for this.

Answer (score 95):

After creating a config file (`~/.ssh/config`) it worked. This is what I had to put in it:

```
Host github.com
User git
Port 22
Hostname github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
TCPKeepAlive yes
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Thanks to @VonC for leading me to there in the comments.

I don't get why I never needed this before though.

Comment: You would need that if your ssh address somehow follows the SCP syntax See my answer for more details.

Comment: GitHub portable automatically updated and I was no longer able to use git. I had to put git in the environment path again and add this file and then all was working again. Thanks!

Comment: This helped me. I have an old version of git (1.9.1) which doesn't seem to respect `sshCommand`. But I could use this technique to specify the `IdentityFile` I wanted to use.

Comment: Great, it worked! It is particularly useful if a user has multiple ssh keys. In my case I specified the second key for IdentityFile and it worked.

Comment: Thanks man, I actually have an old `config` file that point to the wrong ssh key, this reminds me to remove it lol

Comment: Worked for me with or without the last two lines commented out. I think they're extraneous in my setup.

Answer (score 46):

If it ***works for other repositories***, but ***not one in particular***, then you are probably using the wrong remote url(i.e. `https` instead of `git@github.com`)

1. First, double check that your git ssh connection is working:

   ```
    ssh -T git@github.com
   ```
2. If it works, check your remote:

   ```
    git remote -v
   ```

   it will display something like this:

   ```
    origin  https://github.com/ownername/repo(fetch)
    origin  https://github.com/ownername/repo(push)
   ```

   where `ownername` is either your username or your organization name (the "owner" of the repository).
3. If the remotes indicate `https` at the beginning, then you need to change this url with:

   ```
    git remote set-url origin git@github.com:ownername/repo.git
   ```

Go [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) for more details.

Comment: I would also add that this can happen when you clone the repository using https version and not ssh version of clone options.

In this case you will need to change settings of repository link to point to SSH versino which is described in this solution.

Comment: Beware of the trailing `.git` !

Comment: I was only missing step 3 in your description, thanks!

Comment: Oh man. I've spent so long and all I was doing was using the wrong link.

Comment: I couldn't do it because I had the path wrong. In my case I was setting up my SSH on a repo of an organizational account so `username` in `https://github.com/username/repo` was not my personal username but the whole path of orgname/repo. For this cases instructions using "username" might be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting some weird line ending issue in Windows when copying the clone address from github.

Note the extra character before git. It was NOT appearing in my console. It was invisible.

```
git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git ./docker
Cloning into './docker'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.XXX.X' to the list of known hosts.
\302\226git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

It took me a while to notice the `\302\226` before git in the response. Once I saw that, I backspaced before git@ and made sure there was just a space there and it worked.

Comment: Seems the `ssh-agent` is stopped. You may need to start ssh-agent by running the command ` eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` in git bash. Then, you can add all your ssh keys again to the ssh-add by running the commands `ssh-add ~/.ssh/*`

Comment: This was the issue for me. I knew I'd set up SSH correctly. I'd done it many times before. But despite setting it up correctly this error persisted over and over again. I was going insane. Why are there nonsense issues with invisible characters? Not sure how or why this happens but I'm glad you spotted it.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<YOUR-USERNAME>/<YOUR-REPOSITORY>.git
```

Change the items in the <> and run the command, and then try a git push.

Github.com's page on [managing remote repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh) helped me.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub recently underwent an audit of ALL keys.  Go to [the key section of your account](https://github.com/settings/ssh/audit) to re-approve it.

Comment: I've already approved/deleted all the SSH keys. I'm adding new keys now (see my question again) but it just won't work... I've done this many times before without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

For ssh you need to change the url.  Open up the git config file and change the url to

```
url = git@github.com:username/repository.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause is permissions.

This weekend I have had the same problem with a new laptop and been unable to push to github even though my ssh key has been in Github for years.

The permissions on your `~/.ssh/` directory should be `700` and your `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` should be `600`

When I copied my keys to the new laptop my permissions were too permissive.

More info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me after below:

```bash
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

```bash
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Comment: How is this different from VonC's answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a critical security configuration, so please do this with care.

GitHub has just changed their SSH server keys and a manual update is required at client side, the steps are at:

https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/

And the official SSH finger prints to carefully check are at https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints

> **IMPORTANT**: To prevent possible attacks, ensure the new finger prints are the official ones, if unsure, just run `ssh-keygen -R github.com` and try again

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is due to multiple ssh keys used/listed in ~/.ssh folder then it can be fixed by specifying the correct ssh keys with any git command using git environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`. Run this in your terminal under your git repository:

```bash
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_private_key' git submodule update --init
```

Replace `~/.ssh/your_private_key` with the path of ssh private key you wanna use. And you can change the subsequent git command (in the example is `git submodule update --init`) to others like `git pull`, `git fetch`, etc.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43953433/4170265

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when moving from Windows 7 to Windows 10 using Git for Windows.

I had my SSH keys for a Gitlab of our company running on my old computer and using this ssh command in the Windows cmd or the Git Bash worked fine (with git.my_server.com replaced by the Git server domain) - so my Windows was able to use the key, but Git for Windows was not:

```
ssh -T git@git.my_server.com
```

(which displayed: "Welcome to GitLab, @my_username!). However, when trying to clone, push or pull with git, I got the "Permission denied (publickey)" error message.

I initially couldn't find the location/environment of the SSH keys that Git uses, so I tried to copy/paste the ssh keys into this environment by using the Git Bash:

1. Open the Git Bash from the Windows Start Menu (not from a directory). Enter

   `pwd`

   I later found out that this returns the location of your ssh keys. In my case this returned '/u/', which was a network drive mounted as "U:\" in my Windows account.
2. Type cd `.ssh`, then `dir`. This may list your currently existing id files, like id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. I deleted these files since I didn't need them anymore (you might want to skip this if you successfully used other SSH keys on your installation, e.g. for other Git Servers):

   `rm id_rsa`

   `rm id_rsa.pub`
3. Create a new id_rsa file (if you have an existing id_rsa file, you can also use another name, like id_rsa_gitlab_my_username or something like that. Add .pub to this name for the public key):

   `vi id_rsa`
   and press the 'i' on your keyboard to switch to text insertion mode. Now copy the content of your private key file (I had mine in C:\Users\my_windows_username.ssh\id_rsa and used Notepad++ to copy the complete content, Windows notepad works fine as well).
   Press Escape on your keyboard to exit text insertion mode, then enter ':' and 'x', then Enter to save the file. Repeat this for the public key file.
4. If you use multiple SSH keys or used another name for the id_rsa file, you should also create a 'config' file or copy the content of your existing configuration file:

   `vi config`

   (Again, press 'i', insert text, press ':', 'x', then Enter.)
   My file looks like this (use your server, user and SSH file name):

   ```
   #SCC Gitlab
       Host git.my_server.com
       HostName git.my_server.com
       User git
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```

Now my Git for Windows was able to push, pull and clone without problems again.

Answer (score 0):

First, try this (changing your email address as needed)

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "you@yourdomain.com"
```

If you're creating using Cygwin, there might be confusion about the home directory, which is what happened for me, as I was referring to (copying to GitHub) an old/incorrect key from a different directory.
So in case this happens for you, after creating the key, do:

```
$ explorer .
```

Which will pop up a windows explorer window, showing your full/absolute path. That's when I saw the ~ directory was actually my Cygwin directory

```
C:\Program Files\cygwin64\home\{your_username}\.ssh
```

I was then able to copy my private SSH key and paste in GitHub, and cloning, etc.. then worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Gnome. Configuration was alright but keys weren't added to ssh-agent. A reboot did the trick. Gnome Keyring uses it's own ssh-agent.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I have 2 users, both had an SSH key. The first one that was authenticated wasn't the one I needed. So I deleted the SSH key from it.

This command helped me understand which user is being used because of it's output:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit remote URL settings, just follow this step:

1. Open Terminal.
2. Change the current working directory to your local project.
3. List your existing remotes in order to get the name of the remote you want to change.

```
$ git remote -v
```

4. Change your remote's URL from HTTPS to SSH with the `git remote set-url` command.
   change `USERNAME` and `REPOSITORY` as yours.

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

5. Verify that the remote URL has changed.

```
$ git remote -v
```

## Verify new remote URL

now will shows:

> origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
> origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)

After this you will never found Permission denied (`publickey`) and your push will run okay.

Answer (score 0):

In .git/config I changed

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://path/to/the/repo.git
```

to

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:path/to/the/repo.git
```

It started working without any problem.
In addition, if you have previously cloned your project before setting up your SSH key, recloning will solve the problem. Ensure that your local repository is up to date with your remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was related to DNS mapping (bitbuket was not pointing to the correct IP) I fixed it with doing a simple trick (i overwritten the IP address to point when looking for bitbucket.org)

open and edit /etc/hosts in ubuntu (in case of any other OS please look how can you can do the same)

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

and add the following line (in the case of GitHub or any other website look for the IP and do the mapping accordingly)

```
18.205.93.2 bitbucket.org
```

and then it'll resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using sudo to clone the repository like in /var/www/html/ dir:

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:<user>/repos.git
```

I solved it by: adjusting the permissions of directory /var/www/html
sudo chmod a+w -R /var/www/html (use your own permission)
Then I could clone without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an AWS EC2 instance, make sure to have a public IPv4 address. I only had an IPv6 address. GitHub still does not support SSH for IPv6 addresses for clone operations. You can follow the discussion at this link:

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/10539